# How do you verify a signature originated from a given Tezos wallet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, ethereum, cryptocurrency

After connecting to a Tezos wallet, [you can send over a payload requesting it be signed](https://docs.walletbeacon.io/guides/sign-payload).

Given the signature, wallet address, and a pre-defined message (payload) what are the steps to determine the authenticity of that signature.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in C# using [Netezos](https://netezos.dev/) library.

First, you need to obtain the public key for a given wallet address:

```cs
using Netezos.Rpc;

using var rpc = new TezosRpc("https://mainnet-tezos.giganode.io/");

var rawPubKey = await rpc.Blocks.Head.Context.Contracts[address].ManagerKey.GetAsync<string>();
```

Then you can verify the signature:

```cs
using Netezos.Keys;

var pubKey = PubKey.FromBase58(rawPubKey);
var isValid = pubKey.Verify(message, signature);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { verifySignature } from '@taquito/utils';
verifySignature(
  payloadBytes,
  publicKey,
  updateAatarLinkDto.signature,
);
```

You need to include `payloadBytes` and `signature` to verify.